# Is trait extends (A => B) a trait extending function?

Tags: scala

The following trait `Parser[+T]` is a trait that extends a function that accepts an `Input` and returns a `Result[T]`.

```
 trait Parser[+T] extends (Input => Result[T])
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right.

`Input => Result[T]` is a shortcut for `Function1[Input, Result[T]]`.
It has an abstrat method

```
def apply(v1: Input) : Result[T]
```

which when defined will be the actual function implementation.

Scala syntax allows methods called `apply` to be called silently, that is for some expression `e`, `e(x1, ... xn)` will be translated to `e.apply(x1, ... xn)`

Answer (score 6):

Almost. It extends `Function[Input, Result[T]]` - the type of function that takes `Input` as argument and returns `Result[T]` (not `T`) as result.  `Result[T]` carries information about a successful parse into a `T` or an error that occurs during parse.